# Java Enums: Instantiate Enum "dynamically" (more like a class constructor) to use with Jackson

Tags: java, enums, jackson

I have this Enum:

```
public enum Role {

Manager("manager"),
Customer("customer");

private String role;

Role(String role){
    this.role = role;
}
}
```

And I have this POJO which I get from an Http request (using Jerey and Jackson):

```
public class UserCredentials {

private String username;
private String password;
private Role role;

public UserCredentials() {
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}
}
```

The last setter creates an error as Jackson don't really knows how to convert

```
{
"username": "shikloshi",
"password": "password",
"role": "admin"
}
```

To an object (specifially the "role" Enum).

I was trying to change the setter to:

```
public void setRole(String role) {
this.role = new Role(role);
}
```

which cannot be done.

Is there a way to invoke enum constructor (or any other way of creation - Jackson for instance) in a more Object Oriented manner (the alternative is to use a switch-case inside the setter)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common solution in this situation is to add a `public static Role fromString(String)` method in the `Role` enum. Internally it might use a `switch`, or a `Map<String, Role>` cache.

Example using a simple `switch`:

```
public static Role fromString(String string) {
    switch (string) {
        case "manager": return Manager;
        case "customer": return Customer;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid role: " + string);
}
```

Example using a cache:

```
private static Map<String, Role> cache = new HashMap<>();
static {
    for (Role value : values()) {
        cache.put(value.role, value);
    }
}

public static Role fromString(String string) {
    Role role = cache.get(string);
    if (role == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid role: " + string);
    }
    return role;
}
```

Actually, as [@realskeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic) pointed out in a comment,
if you renamed your `enum` values to all-caps, `MANAGER`, `CUSTOMER`,
as recommended by convention,
then you could benefit from the `.valueOf` method which uses a cache behind the scenes:

```
public static Role fromString(String string) {
    return valueOf(string.toUpperCase());
}
```

In this case you don't need to worry about building the cache yourself.
If you supply an invalid string value,
this will raise a `IllegalArgumentException` just like the examples above (with slightly different text).

Comment: Correct, but I would like to add that if OP named his constants according to convention (`MANAGER`, `CUSTOMER`), then it could easily be done with `Role.valueOf(string.toUpperCase())`, which internally relies on a map.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic, that's a great suggestion, updated my post